# Problems with GUI working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Message for Riaan,

I'm getting the same results.

Here is the top where I added the array list:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class FVolume extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
    private JPanel Customers;
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers, NameTextContractors, ExistTextContractors;
```

Now here is where I changed the actionListener

```
    AddCustomers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        { 
        Customers.add(new Customer("Customer")); 
    } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would probably be to add a List field:

```
public class FVolume extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
private JPanel Customers;
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
...
```

Then change your actionListener to this:

```
AddCustomers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    customers.add(new Customer("Customer"));
}
    });
```

With this list you can now simply clear the text area and display the customers from this list when the refresh button is pressed.

A better way would be to use a JDialog for the customer popup (and not to pop it up from the Customer constructor) and then register a listener on the dialog to just notify the main app when a new customer has been saved. Then just add the new customer to the text area (No refresh button needed then). This is a bit more involved though, as you'd need to fire a PropertyChangeEventfrom the Customer dialog on saving (Among other changes you'd need to make).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added what you said where I think it's supposed to go, and it does the same thing.  I changed the above code to display those areas.

Comment: You would also need to add code to the refresh button actually fill the text area from the list contents.